# Resolve Promise in mongoose virtual property?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, async-await, mongoose-schema

I'm using asynchronous virtual properties to count how often that document has been referenced in a specific other collection. [This feature has been added.](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/5762)

```
// Schema mortician.js
const Pickup = require('./pickup')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const mortSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
}, { timestamps: true })

mortSchema.virtual('count').get( async function () {
    return await Pickup.countDocuments({ mortician: this._id })
})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Mortician', mortSchema)
```

However, when I try to render it like this, it's returning a Promise: `Promise { <pending> }` and the displayed value is `[object Promise]`, like joseym describes over here: [Support for Asynchronous Virtual #1894](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1894#issuecomment-336552379)

```
async index(req, res) {
  try {
    const morticians = await Mortician.find({}).exec()
    res.render('pages/morticians', {
      title: 'Bestatter',
      page: req.originalUrl,
      morticians: morticians
    })
  } catch (err) { err => console.log(err) }
..
}
```

Since I'm directly passing the morticians element to render, I've idea where to place the needed `await` for `mortician.count`. I want to avoid looping (`for (const mortician of morticians)`), before passing it to `res.render`. How to solve this?

Does it even make sense, to query (`"OtherSchema".find..`) with in an virtual property? What's best practice?

Answer (score 1):

You need to execute your promise, then save the result in a variable which will be used to render it

something like this

```
async index(req, res) {
  try {
    const morticians = await Mortician.find({}).exec();
    res.render('pages/morticians', {
      title: 'Bestatter',
      page: req.originalUrl,
      morticians: morticians
    })
  } catch (err) {
    err => console.log(err)
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, that's what I'm already using, since I asked [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61726347).. I'll update my questions code.

Comment: I dont see it really you are using an await with a callback which makes no sense, either you have a callback a then chain or an await...

Comment: I'm new to promises and async tasks, that's why I'm asking here. I specified two points which seem unclear to me in my question above.